# How does this Regex function?

Tags: regex

```
output = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(output, "(?s).*kucing(.*?)</tr>", "$1") + "</tr>"
```

I  think the purpose is to do some greedy search.

So if we have `bla bla bla kucing bla bla bla kucing bla bla bla kucing hello world`

It should match hello world. However, I forget how I set that up.

I tried a bunch of regular expression

```
?System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace("Hello World kucing Hi Kitty Kucing I like cat", "(?s)(.*)kucing(.*)", "$2")
" Hi Kitty Kucing I like cat"
    ?System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace("Hello World kucing Hi Kitty Kucing I like cat", "(?s).*kucing(.*)", "$1")
" Hi Kitty Kucing I like cat"
    ?System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace("Hello World kucing Hi Kitty Kucing I like cat", "(?s)(.*)kucing(.*)", "$1")
"Hello World "
    ?System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace("Hello World kucing Hi Kitty Kucing I like cat", "(?s)(.*)kucing(.*)", "$2")
" Hi Kitty Kucing I like cat"
```

What I want is "I like cat". Basically I want the first .* to be greedy and match "Hello World kucing Hi Kitty Kucing". I want it to go the last "Kucing". Then I want to remove that part and grab the rest.

How would I do that?

Comment: The title of this question made my day.

Comment: "What does this regex do" already exists as a question title :O

Comment: I can't get the regex to even run. Getting missing delimiters and unbalanced paren issues.

Comment: @Jan What are you talking about?

Comment: Could you illustrate with a shorter sample code and describe more accurate what you want to achieve? The title is somehow confusing. Obviously you need a new/modified regex or parser solution that does change something in your html. Requirements, input and expected output needed. There is something with `<tr>` and `</tr>` which has a "kucing" before it. To me it's all unclear.

Comment: @bobblebubble Sorry, right you are :)

Comment: @Jacobr365: Sorry, was not meant for you.

Comment: You switched on the single line mode (`(?s)`) where the dot matches everything (including newline characters), then `.*` matches everything afterwards and `kucing` made the engine backtrack. To be honest, this is quite a crappy regex - first for using it on a HTML tree (why not use some decent parser inestead?), second because the engine has to do a lot of backtracking. Either be more precise on what to match or do not use a regex at all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(?s)` switch from multiline (default) to singleline

Also your code don't return expect result because you use `kucing` instead of `Kucing`, when c# regex is case sensitive.

You can use like this:

```
string str = "Hello World kucing Hi Kitty Kucing I like cat";

string s = Regex.Replace(str, "(.*)kucing(.*)", "$2",
    RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);

string s2 = Regex.Replace(str, "(.*)kucing\\s*(.*)", "$2",
    RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);

Console.WriteLine(s);
Console.WriteLine(s2);
```

`\s` mean white space.

Output:

```
 I like cat
I like cat
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters, this site might help you a lot if you want to test your regular expressions: https://regex101.com/
Further to even get this regex to work, you need to at least escape the slash.

```
(?s).*kucing(.*?)<\/tr>
```

> basically I want the regex engine to go to the last "kucing" and then go to to the next after that. And then remove everything up to that point.

Can you please explain a bit more what you intend to do? Logically there would not be a next 'kucing' after the last one. Please clarify.

Comment: actually I wonder why did I put ?s there? Also I want to capture everything after the last kucing